# Hard drive is not detected at early stage of unattended installation

Tags: installation, hp-proliant, automated-install, preseed, usb-boot

I'm doing an unattended installation of Ubuntu-14.04-server with a USB drive and a `preseed` file on different type of servers (HP Proliant ML110, ML310, ML350). This `preseed` file contains multiple rules, including the configuration of `partman-auto` that automates the (custom) partitioning of the server's hard drive.

- On the servers ML110 and ML310, at the beginning of the installation process (before `partman` launches), the hard drive is in `/dev/sda` and the USB drive takes `/dev/sdb`. Therefore, I specify `d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda` in my `preseed` file, and the partitioning is applied on the server's hard drive. Everything works fine.
- But on the servers ML350, at the beginning of the installation process, the main hard drive is **not present on `/dev/sd*`**, and the USB drive takes the `/dev/sda`. It's only a *few steps* later that the hard drive shows up … in `/dev/sdb`. Therefore, my rule in the `preseed` file is no longer valid and `partman` screws-up my USB drive.

This very annoying fact rises two questions:

1. Why the main hard drive doesn't show in the devices at the beginning of the installation process?
2. How could I force the main hard drive to show up (and make it take the `/dev/sda`) or if I cannot, How could I find out, with certainty, on which `/dev/sdX` the main hard drive will be.

I tried to add `dmraid=true` in the kernel options, it didn't work. I also tried to add `pci=conf1` (found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/517761/hard-disk-is-not-detecting-in-intel%C2%AE-server-board-s2600cp)) but without success.

Comment: Do you have any option NOT to use USB for this? I don't deal in the Ubuntu/Debian realm, but my ProLiant servers all use a netbook image or a minimal .ISO mounted via the ILO.

Comment: USB are easy because I can put access keys and remove them once the s server is installed. Nevertheless, I'm going to try the whole process with a CD to see the results but it is not a final option for me, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if in an `presed/early_command` the hard drive was not yet detected, I found out that in the `partman/early_command`, it is!

Therefore, I made a command that sets the `partman-auto/disk` parameter of the `debian-installer` with the correct correct device name, checked at that moment.

For more information about that commad, see [Unattended installation with preseed -- give a custom device to partman-auto](https://serverfault.com/questions/685251/unattended-installation-with-preseed-give-a-custom-device-to-partman-auto)

Answer (score 1):

Ever since the move from the old CCISS driver to the HPSA driver, HP Smart Array controllers now leverage the normal SCSI block device subsystem. Therefore, the device naming scheme is `/dev/sdX`.

Your use of a USB key alters the device enumeration because the USB device is present *before* the RAID controller (you're booting off of it). So the USB key becomes `/dev/sda` and the first HP Smart Array RAID controller is `/dev/sdb`.

Modern Linux operating systems use partition labels or UUIDs, so the device name won't matter upon first boot (*[after you've removed the USB key](https://serverfault.com/a/658175/13325)*).

The difference between your platforms may be that the ML110 and ML310 (you didn't specify generations) are not using Smart Array controllers, or have a different class of RAID device.

The ML350 *does* have a proper Smart Array controller, so the behavior you're seeing is to be expected.

Use a different preseed file, or try a different deployment approach if possible.

Comment: I tried a different approach: with a (quite long) `d-i partman/early_command`, I managed to identify the device `/dev/sdX` that needs to be passed to `d-i partman-auto/disk`. But I don't know how to pass the result since this option expects a `string`…