# Unattended installation with preseed -- give a custom device to partman-auto

Tags: automated-install, unattended, preseed, usb-boot

I'm doing an unattended installation of Ubuntu-14.04-server with a USB drive and a preseed file on different type of servers (HP Proliant ML110, ML310, ML350).

- On the ML110 and ML310, the hard drive is in `/dev/sda` and the USB drive takes `/dev/sdb`.
- While on the servers ML350, the USB drive takes the `/dev/sda` and the hard drive shows up in `/dev/sdb`.

As this should be a completely unattended installation, regardless of the server type, I need to find a way to give the correct device path to `d-i partman-auto/disk`.

My first idea was to force the hard drive to show up before the USB drive, allowing it to take `/dev/sda` on the ML350 servers ; but [I didn't find a way do that](https://serverfault.com/questions/684684/hard-drive-is-not-detected-at-early-stage-of-unattended-installation).

Therefore, I made a small script that detects the device name just before `partman` executes, and record that in a variable `$INSTALL_DEV`:

```
d-i partman/early_command string                                  \
    for DEV in `ls /sys/block | grep sd`; do                      \
        if [ -n "`ls -l /sys/block/$DEV | grep /usb`" ]; then     \
            USB_DEV=/dev/${DEV};                                  \
            echo "USB_DEV is $USB_DEV" >> /var/log/syslog;        \
        else                                                      \
            INSTALL_DEV=/dev/${DEV};                              \
            echo "INSTALL_DEV = $INSTALL_DEV" >> /var/log/syslog; \
            break;                                                \
        fi;                                                       \
    done;                                                         \
```

Since then, I'm struggeling to find a way to give that variable to `d-i partman-auto/disk`. I thought of different alternatives but I couldn't find a way to implement one of them:

1. Make the `partma-auto/disk` interpret a variable. But unfortunately it only takes a string as a value.
2. Modify the `debian-installer` database where I hope the preseeded values are stored. But I didn't find the database file (neither the way to alter it).
3. Make a script that includes a tiny preseed file with the correct device. But I can only include files from `preseed/include`, before the hard drive shows in `/dev`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple `partman/early_command` that does the exactly what I wanted

```
d-i partman/early_command \
    string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(echo /dev/`ls -l /sys/block/[hs]d* | grep -v "usb" | head -n1 | sed 's/^.*\([hs]d[a-z]\+\).*$/\1/'`)"
```

This `early-command` is executed just before `partman` executes. It dynamically sets the value of `partman-auto/disk` configuration of the `debian-installer`.

The command between `$(` and `)` outputs the first hard drive found that is not an USB drive.

Comment: What is `debconf-set`? I can't find any documentation for that. It doesn't seem to exist? Is this some special alias for `debconf-set-selections`?

Comment: @BradleyOdell It's part of `debian-installer-utils`, see [this](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer-utils/blob/master/debconf-set).

Comment: This is a great solution!  Just a couple notes:  `"$(echo /dev/$(...))"` is equivalent to `"/dev/$(...)"`.  You don't need two levels of command substitution, just one.  And, here's a version that supports NVME drives:  `d-i partman/early_command string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "/dev/$(ls -l /sys/block/* |grep '[hs]d[a-z]\+\|nvme[0-9]\+n[0-9]\+' |grep -v usb |head -n1 |sed 's/^.*\([hs]d[a-z]\+\|nvme[0-9]n[0-9]\).*$/\1/')"`